# Can't load json result using angular in a select tag

Tags: angularjs, json, tags

[image]

So I have here an angular code to fetch json records. It's all working good. But it does not display on the view. I wanted the json results to be displayed on a select tag, here's the code for the view part

```
<div class="col s6 input-field" ng-controller="positionController">
<select id="selectPosition" ng-model="selectedPosition" ng-options="item as item.PosDesc for item in records">
</select>
<label>Choose Position</label>
</div>
```

But it doesn't display anything on the view. Is there something wrong with my code? Thank you.

edit : here's the json value 
[image]

Comment: Post real code,  not pictures of code we can't read or copy into answers

Comment: What @charlietfl says and there could be something wrong with your code but that would be rather hard to say without you sharing the data your response is supposed to be returning. Without that there is no way of knowing if your `ng-options` expression is correct.

Comment: could you show the value of records?

Comment: I've updated my post. i've added the values

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

Check this demo.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.filter("capitalize", function() {
    return function(input, all) {
      var reg = (all) ? /([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g : /([^\W_]+[^\s-]*)/;
      return (!!input) ? input.replace(reg, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
      }) : "";
    };
  });

  app.controller("positionController", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/dfbb68cffa626c2e29b3/raw/5c6fc8c1f7529fe25a6a848e9154c5b778dd3eb3/jsonFile.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.records = response;
        $scope.selectedPosition = $scope.records[0];
      });
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div class="col s6 input-field" ng-controller="positionController">
    <select id="selectPosition" ng-model="selectedPosition" ng-options="item as item.PosDesc for item in records">
    </select>
    <label>Choose Position</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[image: JSFiddle]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-model="selectedPosition" to ng-model="(selectedPosition | json)". To display in select use angular code like:

```
<select id="selectPosition" ng-model="(selectedPosition | json)" 
   ng-options="item as item.PosDesc for item in records">
   {{ selectedPosition | json }}
</select>
```